# Create a wsdl from wcf for receive specif xml template

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, wsdl

i'm having a problem with a WCF that i need to create, i have this client
that send me a XML with something like this.

Client XML:

```
<otm:Bejeto xmlns:otm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4" xmlns:gtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gtm/transmission/v6.4">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <otm:InnerProp>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <otm:A>?</otm:A>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <otm:B>?</otm:B>
         </otm:InnerProp>
      </otm:Bejeto>
```

But my wsdl expects a xml like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:otm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <otm:AddXmlString>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <otm1:Bejeto xmlns:otm="?" xmlns:gtm="?" xmlns:otm1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <otm1:InnerProp>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <otm1:A>?</otm1:A>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <otm1:B>?</otm1:B>
         </otm1:InnerProp>
      </otm1:Bejeto>
   </otm:AddXmlString>
</soapenv:Body>
```

</soapenv:Envelope>

This is my c# class

```
       [DataContract(Namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm")]
     public class Bejeto
     {
         [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", AttributeName = "otm")]
         public string otm { get; set; }
    
         [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", AttributeName = "gtm")]
         public string gtm { get; set; }
    
         [DataMember(Name = "InnerProp"),
             XmlElement(Namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm")]
         public InnerClass InnerProp { get; set; }
     }
    
     [DataContract(Namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm")]
     public class InnerClass
     {
         [DataMember(Name = "A")]
         public string A { get; set; }
    
         [DataMember(Name = "B")]
         public string B { get; set; }
     }
```

And my contract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm"), XmlSerializerFormat()]
public interface INissanServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    string PlannedShipment(Bejeto Bejeto)
```

I Don't know why this happens

Comment: Hello, please share the code instead of images of it. This makes editing/changes easier for other users.

Comment: Ok, done @F_Schmidt, sorry by that.

Comment: You just need to add the The envelope string to the xml string that comes from the client.  You can use string methods string finalXml = "Envelope Prefix" + "client xml" + "Envelope Suffix";